# numpy sum slower than string count

Tags: python, string, numpy, count

I was comparing the performance of counting how many letters 'C' are in a very long string, using a `numpy array` of characters and the string method `count`.
**genome** is a very long string.

```
g1 = genome 
g2 =  np.array([i for i in genome])

%timeit np.sum(g2=='C')                                                                                                                                                                             
4.43 s ± 230 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit g1.count('C')                                                                                                                                                                               
955 ms ± 6.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each).
```

I expected that a numpy array would compute it faster but I am wrong.

Can someone explain me how the count method works and what is it faster than using a numpy array?

Thank you!

Comment: How it works? Did you check the source code?

Comment: I think your test is not fair because `g2=='C'` will create a new array which contains `[True, False...]`, while `g1.count('C')` only needs to trace a number.

Comment: Well, `np.sum(g2=='C')` has to iterate the array twice + create a new array. Once for creating the index mask where `g2=='C'` and then summing. `g1.count('C')` only has to iterate once. Even though

Comment: A more fair test would be, instead of `g1.count`, `sum(i=='C' for i in genome)`

Comment: Well, numpy is *numeric* python - if you're dealing with strings python's standard operations are better optimized and probably a better choice.

Comment: While still slower than str.count, a more fair test would be using `numpy`'s string operations, `np.char.count(genome, 'C')`, which will be faster than your initial test.

Comment: What is the performance using `bincount`? You would have to create a view of your array though: `np.bincount(g2.view('i4'))`. Note it would also return the counts for other values

Comment: `np.char.count` just applies the string method to each element of the array.

Comment: String count like most of the string methods is written in compiled code.  Why shouldn't it be (relatively) fast?  `numpy` is fast when it too is using compiled code.  In your case it has to take (atleast) two passes through the array, once to test for 'C', and once to sum the `True` values.

Comment: I get the point that numpy first creates the index and then counts while string.count sums summulatively during a single iteration and therefore looping twice in numpy vs python would make it about 2x slower. BUT is >4x slower. 
Excuse me for my ignorance, but what @hpaulj means with numpy possibly not being compiled?

Comment: %timeit `np.bincount(g2.view('i4'))`.                                                                                                                                                          
2.72 s ± 54.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each). 
%timeit `np.char.count(genome, 'C')`                                                                                                                                                                     
2.97 s ± 76.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each). %timeit `sum(i=='C' for i in genome)`. 
indeed forever

Answer (score 2):

Let's explore some variations on the problem.  I won't try to make as large a string as yours.

```
In [393]: astr = 'ABCDEF'*10000
```

First the string count:

```
In [394]: astr.count('C')                                                            
Out[394]: 10000
In [395]: timeit astr.count('C')                                                     
70.2 µs ± 115 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Now try a 1 element array with that string:

```
In [396]: arr = np.array(astr)                                                       
In [397]: arr.shape                                                                  
Out[397]: ()
In [398]: np.char.count(arr, 'C')                                                    
Out[398]: array(10000)
In [399]: timeit np.char.count(arr, 'C')                                             
200 µs ± 2.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [400]: arr.dtype                                                                  
Out[400]: dtype('<U60000')
```

My experience with other uses of `char` is that it iterates on the array elements and applies the string method.  So it can't be faster than applying the string method directly.  I suppose the rest of the time is some sort of numpy overhead.

Make a list from the string - one character per list element:

```
In [402]: alist = list(astr)                                                         
In [403]: alist.count('C')                                                           
Out[403]: 10000
In [404]: timeit alist.count('C')                                                    
955 µs ± 18.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The list count has to loop through the elements, and do the test against `C` each time.  Still it is faster than `sum(i=='C' for i in alist)` (and variants).

Now make an array from that list - single character elements:

```
In [405]: arr1 = np.array(alist)                                                     
In [406]: arr1.shape                                                                 
Out[406]: (60000,)
In [407]: timeit arr1=='C'                                                           
634 µs ± 12.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [408]: timeit np.sum(arr1=='C')                                                   
740 µs ± 23.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The `np.sum` is relatively fast.  It's the check against 'C' that takes the most time.

If I construct a numeric array of the same size, the count time is quite a bit faster.  The equality test against a number is faster than the equivalent string test.

```
In [431]: arr2 = np.resize(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]),arr1.shape[0])                    
In [432]: np.sum(arr2==3)                                                            
Out[432]: 10000
In [433]: timeit np.sum(arr2==3)                                                     
155 µs ± 1.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`numpy` does not promise to be faster for all Python operations.  For the most part when working string elements, it is heavily dependent on Python's own string code.